# Reset unity AR session to find trackable planes on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Trackable planes become infinite when detected by an iOS device. Due to this, the upper most plane under the camera lens will always be detected. There is no way of getting back to the lower plane except for lowering the camera through the top plane. How can you reset the plane in the view?

Using Unity 2018.3 with AR Foundation 1.5.0-preview 6

```cs
 private void UpdatePlacementPose()
    {
        var screenCenter = Camera.current.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
        var hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
        arRaycast.Raycast(screenCenter, hits, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.Planes);

        placementPoseIsValid = hits.Count > 0;
        if (placementPoseIsValid)
        {
            placementPose = hits[0].pose;

            var cameraForward = Camera.current.transform.forward;
            var cameraBearing = new Vector3(cameraForward.x, 0, cameraForward.z).normalized;
            placementPose.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(cameraBearing);
        }
    }
}
```

The floor is detected and an infinite plane is created, but then a table top is detected and an infinite plane is detected at this greater height. This means that the floor will no longer be registered since the upper plane is always blocking the camera's line of sight to the lower plane. The only way to get back to the lower plane is to physically move the camera below the upper plane so there is no planes in the way of the camera view.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.Planes
```

To

```
UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon
```

Confusingly, the Planes enum value includes 4 different types of planes, including PlaneWithinInfinity, causing your undesired effect.

PlaneWithinPolygon will instead cause the AR Raycast to only detect hits within the boundaries of detected planes.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arsubsystems@2.1/api/UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.html